# Third person view using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, camera, transformation

I've been scratching my head trying to get this working all day.

I'm using OpenGL in Visual Studio to make a vehicle the player can drive around. The camera should, naturally, maintain a fixed distance above and behind.

I thought I could just rotate the camera on its own local y-axis to match the rotation of the vehicle, and then rotate the camera around the y-axis of the vehicle similarly. (Like it's orbiting the vehicle) However it's been producing a lot of unpredictable effects. I have the first rotation working, it's the second, around the vehicle, which is causing problems. Here are the relevant bits:

```
mat4 view = identity_mat4();
mat4 vehicle = identity_mat4();

vehicle = translate(vehicle, vec3(x_position, 0.f, z_position)); // User input values

view = rotate_about_y(vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f), view, y_rotation); // Rotate camera , this works
// view = rotate_about_y(vec3(x_position, 0.f, z_position), view, y_rotation); // Stay behind vehicle
glUniformMatrix4fv(view_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, view.m);

glUniformMatrix4fv(matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, tank_global.m);
```

This is my method for rotating around a point. I realize what I most likely have to do - adapt this method so I can give it any point, not just the origin, and it will rotate around it. You can see evidence of my most recent attempt in the "center" vector.

```
mat4 rotate_about_y(vec3 center, mat4 in, float deg)
{
    vec3 returnToPoint = vec3(in.m[12], in.m[13], in.m[14]);
    vec3 toOrigin = center - vec3(in.m[12], in.m[13], in.m[14]);
    in = translate(in, toOrigin);
    in = rotate_y_deg(in, deg);
    in = translate(in, returnToPoint);
    return in;
}
```

Or maybe there's an entirely different better way to do this?

Comment: Rotations can get complicated - usually it's easier to work with points. Can you write a function that takes a camera position and a target point that positions the camera correctly? Calculate the position behind the car, and point the camera at the car.

Comment: @orlp I was actually trying to use the sin/cos of the y_rotation variable earlier, and it, too, was giving me trouble. I thought this would be easier. :/

Comment: I'd suggest a similar strategy as orlp -- instead of doing this kind of "rotate and then translate backwards" kind of way you are doing, try to find/make a way to do this using points -- camera position and lookat target. That should be easy to test in isolation to make sure it's working, and if it's working, it should be much easier to solve this kind of problem with it in your arsenal -- at least until you get a bit more comfortable with transformations and matrices to avoid spending too much time debugging these kinds of things.